# Fetching data from api is printing as HTML in page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

1. My data is having HTML as below

> ```
> <p> Are you looking for a camera that will help you capture memorable moments with high clarity? If so, then Nikon D3200 24.2 MP
> ```
>
> Digital SLR Camera is the answer

2. Fetching the data is as below

   var description=$.trim(products.description);
3. My requirement is HTML tags should apply while displaying in page using jquery. Please help with this !!

Comment: You want to use jQuery `.html( htmlString )` to display HTML formatted data http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return the HTML by converting all applicable characters to HTML entities using [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) PHP function.

So convert your String in **PHP** API like this,

```
$string="<p>Are you looking for a camera that will help you capture memorable moments with high clarity? If so, then Nikon D3200 24.2 MP Digital SLR Camera is the answer</p>";

$string=htmlentities($string);
```

Above code will make the returned string like this,

```
&lt;p&gt;Are you looking for a camera that will help you capture memorable moments with high clarity? If so, then Nikon D3200 24.2 MP Digital SLR Camera is the answer&lt;/p&gt;
```

Which includes **HTML entities**,

Now when you set this string as HTML on page using jQuery OR Javascript, you will able to see HTML as it is on the page.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Demo: https://eval.in/600050

---

If you want to set the HTML as it is on the HTML page, you can use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) jQuery method.

So your code would look something line this,

```
var someHtmlString = "<p>Are you looking for a camera that will help you capture memorable moments with high clarity? If so, then Nikon D3200 24.2 MP Digital SLR Camera is the answer</p>";
$("div#DIV_ID").text(someHtmlString);
```

Above code will set **HTML** as is, without forcing it to render HTML.

**jFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/b3pr4qtb/

---

If you want to show **HTML** from API, which means showing bullet list and etc..
 You can use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) jQuery function.

So your code should look something like this,

```
var someHtmlString = "<ul><li>Are you looking for a camera that will help you capture memorable moments with high clarity? If so, then Nikon D3200 24.2 MP Digital SLR Camera is the answer</li></ul>";
$("div#DIV_ID").html(someHtmlString);
```

**jFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/b3pr4qtb/1/

Comment: i need in jquery please

Comment: Do want to remove the HTML tags or show them as it is ? In alert it is showing as HTML entities so that should not be problem if you don't want to remove them.

Comment: i dont want to remove, i want that html to apply means <p> tag means text should come to next line, ol and li tag means bullets should come, etc